# Maximum Update Depth exceeded and not updating state inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why am I getting Maximum update depth exceeded when using this code?

I am not updating the results variable inside the useEffect, I don't see why it's caused an infinite loop. If I remove useSearch and use other array as input for the useTable, it works.

I import both hooks in a component and call them, the result from useSearch is used inside useTable, and setSearchTerm is used in a search field. But using the result from useTable it's causing an infinite loop, still cannot figure out the reason behind it. I'd really appreciate some help!

```
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const results = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let rowData = Object.values(data[i]);
      for (let j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
       
        if (rowData[j].toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
          results.push({ ...data[i], num: i+1 });
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return [[...results],setSearchTerm];
  }
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [results,setSearchTerm]=useSearch(materials);

const calculateRange = (data, rowsPerPage) => {
    const range = [1];
    const num = Math.ceil(data.length / rowsPerPage);
    let i = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
      range.push(i);
    }
    return range;
  };
  
  const sliceData = (data, page, rowsPerPage) => {
    return data.slice((page - 1) * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage);
  };

const useTable = (data, page, rowsPerPage) => {
  const [tableRange, setTableRange] = useState([]);
  const [slice, setSlice] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const range = calculateRange(data, rowsPerPage);
    setTableRange([...range]);

    const slice = sliceData(data, page, rowsPerPage);
    setSlice([...slice]);
  }, [data, setTableRange, page, setSlice,rowsPerPage]);

  return { slice, range: tableRange };
};

const { slice, range } = useTable(results, page, 5);
```